# Getting the disk usage of a file within a hadoop cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am attempting to write a monitor that will test for undersized files within an HDFS cluster, and have been running into issues.

Essentially, I am trying to write a program that parses through a series of directories, and if it finds a directory with less than 5MB on it, it raises a flag.

It appears that using filestatus.getLen() and fileStatus.getBlockSize() are both unhelpful when it comes to discovering disk usage of a file, and I am at a loss when it comes to finding another function that might do this.

Thank you to whoever can hep me with this.

Comment: What issue are you having with these 2 methods exactly? They should give you what you need.

Comment: Are you trying to call `FileStatus.getLen()` on a directory path, or an actual file path? Can you post code as to what you currently have?

Comment: In my experience, I've had to sum the sizes of the actual files in a directory to know the total size. The same approach goes for block size I guess: if `FileStatus.isDirectory()` then you need to traverse files. `FileSystem.listFiles(directory.getPath(), true)` is your friend to find all the files.

Comment: Also check out Twitter's [HDFS-DU](https://github.com/twitter/hdfs-du)